# jekyll heroku deployment issue

Tags: heroku, jekyll

I deployed a jekyll site to heroku. Logs indicate that the app status has changed from "starting to up" (shown below).

```
Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 8:32 -w 3 -p 3641`
[4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[4] * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[4] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 32
[4] * Environment: production
[4] * Process workers: 3
[4] * Phased restart available
[4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3641
[4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
Generating site: /app -> /app/_site
[4] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
Generating site: /app -> /app/_site
[4] - Worker 2 (pid: 14) booted, phase: 0
Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
Generating site: /app -> /app/_site
[4] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

But when I hit my url it gives me "Jekyll is currently rendering the site.
Please try again shortly." No matter how long i wait it says the same thing. I repeated deployment several times but it still gives the same message.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by adding an assets:precompile rake task to my Rakefile. Originally, my Rakefile looked like this:

```
task :build do
  system('bundle exec jekyll build')
end
```

My build task alone wasn't hooking into Heroku's build process, causing `rack-jekyll` to serve its wait page infinitely.
Here's the Rakefile that worked for me:

```
task :build do
  system('bundle exec jekyll build')
end

namespace :assets do
  task precompile: :build
end
```